# Error: LaTeX failed to compile test_report.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See test_report.log for more info

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, tinytex

I'm using R and RStudio in a new laptop and the installation is quite recent. I'm trying to knit a very simple PDF (so far just text in english and some data reading). Knitting to html works but pdf gives the following error message:

```
tlmgr update --all --self
tlmgr.pl: package repository http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr.pl install: package already present: l3backend
! Undefined control sequence.
l.78 dificulties.\n
                   \n 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile test_report.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See test_report.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

I've installed tinytex with `tinytex::install_tinytex(), giving the following output (as far as I understand it worked?)

```
trying URL 'https://yihui.org/tinytex/TinyTeX-1.zip'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 129366587 bytes (123.4 MB)
downloaded 123.4 MB

3 File(s) copied
1 File(s) copied
Running fc-cache -v -r
tlmgr option repository "http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet"
tlmgr.pl: setting default package repository to http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr.pl: updating C:/Users/caio.oliveira/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
tlmgr update --list
tlmgr.pl: package repository http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr.pl: no updates available
```

What can I do?

Comment: From the error message `!Undefined control sequence.` and `l.78 dificulties.\n` the issue seems to be that you tried to add a manual line break using `\n`  (in line 78 of your Rmd). Adding this to a e.g. default Rmd gives me the same error. Instead you could simply use `\\`.